# Ansible dynamic hosts skips

Tags: ansible, stdout, ansible-inventory

I am trying to set up a very hacky vm deployment Environment utilizing ansible 1.9.4 for my homeoffice.

I am pretty far, but the last step just won't work. I have a written 10loc plugin which generates temporary dns names for the staging vlan and I want to pass that value as a host to the next playbook role.

```
    TASK: [localhost-eval | debug msg="{{ hostvars['127.0.0.1'].dns_record.stdout_lines }}"] ***
    ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
        "msg": "['vm103.local', 'vm-tmp103.local']"
    }
```

It's accessible in the global playbook scope via the hostvars:

```
{{ hostvars['127.0.0.1'].dns_record.stdout_lines[1] }}
```

and should be passed on to:

```
    - name: configure vm template
      hosts: "{{ hostvars['127.0.0.1'].dns_record.stdout_lines[1] }}"
      gather_facts: no
      roles:
        - template-vm-configure
```

which results in:

```
PLAY [configure vm template] **************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched
```

my inventory looks like this and seems to work. Hardcoding 'vm-tmp103.local' 
gets the role running.

```
[vm]
vm[001:200].local
[vm-tmp]
vm-tmp[001:200].local
```

Thank you in advance, hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. Plan B would consists of passing the dns-records to a bash script for finalizing configuration, since I just want to configure the Network interface before adding the vm to the monitoring.

Edit:
Modified a play to use add hosts and add them to a temp group
- add_host: name={{ hostvars['127.0.0.1'].dns_record.stdout_lines[1] }} groups=just_vm

but it still doesn't match.

Comment: I don't see a problem. If those hosts indeed are in the inventory it should not result in "no hosts matched". As an alternative to adding the hosts to the inventory, you could use the add_host module: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/add_host_module.html

Comment: Got it, but doesn't seem to work either, it still says no hosts matched.<pre>ok: [vh-desktop.local] => {"new_host": "vm-tmp103.local"}

PLAY [configure vm template] **************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched
</pre>

Comment: That's really strange. I used to use the `add_host` way in Ansible 1.9.4 so I at least know there is not a general issue with that in this version. Both variants should have worked, IMHO.

Comment: You're not calling ansible-playbook with a `--limit` parameter, are you?

Comment: No, it's fully generic. I tried everything now, groups, matching groups, replacing : with a dash in the inventory. Still hardcoding seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not intended behaviour I think.
[#9733](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/9733#issuecomment-90938777) lead me to a solution.

Adding this task let's me use staging as a group.

```
  tasks:
    - set_fact: hostname_next="{{ hostvars['127.0.0.1'].dns_record.stdout_lines[1] }}"
    - add_host: group=staging name='{{ hostname_next }}'
```